# Excel Dynamic Gantt Chart for time schedule

Tags: excel, time, charts, schedule

I have Gantt Chart to simulate MS Project time schedule for project. Everything works fine and I am getting what I want is I have all cells filled. If I have "empty" cells my time schedule displays incorrectly.

"Task Name" in column D
"Start Date" in column E
"End Date" in column F
"Duration" in column G

For column D values are inserted from other sheet by formula `=IF('Other Data'!A1="";"";'Other Data'!A1)`. So if there is no data in column A on sheet "Other data" I am getting empty cell ""
For column E and F user is manually enetering values by calling out so called "Calendar Form".
For column G I have formula to count working days `=IF(E1="";"";NETWORKDAYS(E1;F1))`

I have created Gantt Chart with following settings:

```
="Start Date"
='Time schedule'!$E$1:$E$121
="Duration"
='Time schedule'!$G$1:$G$121
```

For Task Names:

```
='Time schedule'!$D$1:$D$121
```

The problem is that if I have cells with formula like `=IF('Other Data'!A1="";"";'Other Data'!A1)` that gives cells value as "" I get my time schedule messed up. If I leave cells with values and delete all cells with such a formulas that entering "" everyhting works fine. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: you probably should try returning NA() instead of empty string

Comment: Thank you for the tip! That works for Gantt Chart but now I have "#N/A" visible in cells. How I can get rid of "#N/A" and see empty cell instead?

Comment: Ok. One option is to use Conditional Formatting with '=ISNA(A1)'